# Ошибка "E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical"

Tags: delphi

В Delphi XE2 Компилятор ругается на функции `WriteProcessMemory` и `ReadProcessMemory`, выдавая ошибку

> error E2033: E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical

В Delphi7 всё работает замечательно.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался?

Comment: Не стесняемся, показываем код. Но сообщение компилятора, вроде бы, и так достаточно красноречиво: вы, передавая параметры, пытаетесь вызвать приведение типа.

 В Delphi 7 все могло прокатывать, например, потому что дельфёвая обертка к WinAPI-шному WriteProcessMemory  выглядела немного иначе.

Comment: Любой пример для Delphi7, содержащий вышеуказанные функции, выдает такую ошибку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сравним определение методов в 2010 (7ки под рукой нет) и XE2:

```
//Delphi 2010
function ReadProcessMemory(hProcess: THandle; const lpBaseAddress: Pointer; lpBuffer: Pointer;
  nSize: DWORD; var lpNumberOfBytesRead: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
function WriteProcessMemory(hProcess: THandle; const lpBaseAddress: Pointer; lpBuffer: Pointer;
  nSize: DWORD; var lpNumberOfBytesWritten: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;

//Delphi XE2
function ReadProcessMemory(hProcess: THandle; const lpBaseAddress: Pointer;
  lpBuffer: Pointer; nSize: SIZE_T; var lpNumberOfBytesRead: SIZE_T): BOOL; stdcall;
function WriteProcessMemory(hProcess: THandle; const lpBaseAddress: Pointer;
  lpBuffer: Pointer; nSize: SIZE_T; var lpNumberOfBytesWritten: SIZE_T): BOOL; stdcall;
```

Т.е. все что нужно - это явно указать тип данных для переменной, передаваемой в качестве `lpNumberOfBytesWritten`, как `SIZE_T`.

`SIZE_T`, очевидно, появился с поддержкой 64-битных систем.

Comment: Я вас люблю.. я вам раньше не говорил?))))))

Comment: Нет, не случалось )